# Unable to Install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop version on HP Proliant ML10 Gen9 Server

Tags: 18.04

I just bought an HP ML10 Gen9 Server and tried installing Ubuntu but unable to install it. First I tried with Legacy mode only black screen with blinking cursor appeared . After that tried with UFI mode it went into installation page , when I selected install Ubuntu again the screen went blank and display got disconnected ... Plz help me with installation procedure ...